# Edit a record with firebase react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have spent hours searching and experimenting with my code but haven't been able to figure it out. I believe I'm pretty close to my end goal and I apologise in advance if I missed something silly,

So I been trying to create a Notes app with **React** and using **Firebase** realtime db for storing information, I was able to figure out how to create, display & delete records in real time however the edit has be bugged out.

[image: Picture of my console and REACT dev tools]

As you can see the update function works however its only updating the 'first' document from the list of my notes regardless of whichever note I select.

My code is as follows -

Post.js

```
<div className="post_head" id={id}>
        <span className="is-pulled-right delBut" onClick={handleDelete}>
          <i className="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>&nbsp;
        </span>
        <span className="is-pulled-right delBut" onClick={openModal}>
          <i className="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
        </span>

        <p className="post_tit">{name}</p>
        <p className="post-note block">{message}</p>
        

        <div class="modal">

 <Modal id = {id} key = {id} />
</div>
      </div>
```

Modal.js

```
function Modal({message, id}) {
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

const updateDoc = () => {

  
 const cityRef = doc(db, 'posts', id);
setDoc(cityRef, { message: input, id: id, description: 'yooo', name: 'author', timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), photoUrl: '' });
console.log('record updated')
console.log(id);

  };

  return (
    <>
      <div class="modal-background is-clipped" id={id} key={id}></div>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div className="box">
          <textarea
            value={input}
            className="textarea"
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            id = {id}
          ></textarea>
          <button className="button" onClick={updateDoc}></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        class="modal-close is-large"
        aria-label="close"
        onClick={closeModal}
      ></button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Modal;
}
```

Comment: I think we're missing just a little bit of extra info. How is `openModal` declared? I suspect it might be something in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the doc its preferable to use one of the two methods:

- `updateDoc(...)`
- `setDoc(cityRef, {<your_payload>}, {merge: true})`.

Using `setDoc()` with `{merge:true}` is equivalent to `updateDoc()`

One way of ensuring you have the correct document reference is to use string interpolation as follows:

```js
const cityRef = doc(db, `posts/${id}`);
```

Lastly, I would suggest migrating your system to use Cloud Firestore if you haven't already built a large amount of it on RTDB.

It is newer and has a lot of the same features you might enjoy from RTDB with better documentation and a larger community of people to seek help from.